# wordpress плагин не может получить допполя записи

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал плагин для постинга в дискорд. Отдельный тип записи, со своими допполями. Тестировал вывод полей в цикле (вывод всех полей в archive-cta.php) - выводятся. в плагине же не работает. То есть - постить постит, но допполя не вытягивает. get_the_title($postid) вытянуло без проблем.

````
  function cta_send_notification( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
        $sxss=get_post_type();
      if(
          'publish' === $new_status && 
        'publish' !== $old_status && 
        $sxss == 'cta'
      ) {
           function postToDiscord($message)
    {
        $data = array(
            "content" => $message,
            "username" => "CTA PING BOT",
        );
        $curl = curl_init("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/idchannel/key");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        return curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    }  


    $postid =get_the_ID();
    $taste=get_the_title($postid);
    global $post;
    // get post meta 
    $pstmt1=get_post_meta( $postid, 'wpcf-fleetformat', true );




    $message="**";
     $message.=$taste;
     $message.=' ** 
    ```
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    Location: UALX-3
    Datetime:  10.08.18 20:00 ET
    FleetFormat:  '.$pstmt1.'
    FC: TBD
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    ```';


    postToDiscord($message);
      }
    }
    add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'cta_send_notification', 10, 3 );
````

подозреваю что поля записываются в бд после публикации. и они еще не попадают в бд, а я пробую их получить

````
function cta_send_notification( $post_id ) {
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) || get_post($post_id)->post_status != 'publish' ) 
{
        return;
}       
function postToDiscord($message){
    $data = array(
        "content" => $message,
        "username" => "CTA PING BOT",
    );
    $curl = curl_init("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/айди/кей");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    return curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
  };

$postid =get_the_ID();
$taste=get_the_title($postid);

// get post meta 
$pstmt1=get_post_meta($postid, 'wpcf-date-time', true );




$message="**";
 $message.=$taste;
 $message.=' ** 
```
------------------------------
ID '.$postid.'
Title  '.$taste.'
post meta :  '.$pstmt1.'
------------------------------
```';
postToDiscord($message);

}

add_action( 'save_post_cta', 'cta_send_notification', 99999, 1 );
````

Переделал под save_post. результат тот же. айди и тайтл нормально тянет. допполя не вытягивает

Comment: А зачем transition_post_status? Есть же событие save_post.

Comment: transition_post_status для того, чтобы отправлять в дискорд только при первой публикации. save_post будет срабатывать всегда
 "Событие срабатывающее всякий раз, когда запись (пост, страница) создается или обновляется, в том числе при публикации через импорт, xmlrpc или по email."

Comment: А вы мой ответ прочитали?

Comment: @KAGGDesign да, спасибо за ответ! сейчас буду переделывать через save_post. я тоже думаю, что оно сперва шлет в бд стандартные поля (тайтл, текст поста), потом меняет статус на паблишед, а потом уже закидывает в бд допполя. поэтому они и пустые у меня(

Comment: @KAGGDesign переделал под save_post, те же грабли( код в вопросе сверху добавил. работает фильтр под тип записи. вытягивает айди и тайтл. и все.... допполя дальше недоступны

Comment: ну тогда надо копать код вашего плагина что пишет wpcf-date-time и смотреть, когда он сохраняет поля

Comment: и да, выкиньте уже get_the_ID() из вашего кода. Он может неправильно работать в данной ситуации. Вам post_id передан, используйте его. И еще - ставить число параметров в 1, когда их 3 - неправильно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81904/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, скорее всего, в том, что поле `wpcf-fleetformat` обновляется по событию `save_post`. Это обычное действие.

Попробуйте повесить вашу `cta_send_notification()` на `save_post`. Заголовок будет выглядеть так:

```
function cta_send_notification( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
```

где аргументы: id поста, сам пост, bool - это обновление существующего поста или нет.

А объявление своего хука должно использовать более низкий приоритет (чтобы хук выполнялся позже), например

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'cta_send_notification', 999999, 3 );
```